# Not found error - while trying to return a view

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

In `Controller`:

```
public String saveAnswer(@Valid @ModelAttribute("answer") AnswerModel answer,BindingResult result,Model model) {
   System.out.println("saveanswer");
   if(result.hasErrors()) {
    return "question-detail/"+2;
}
```

Question: how to return "question-detail/"+2 ?

I am getting this error while I trying to do so -

```
"JSP file [/WEB-INF/question-detail/2.jsp]" not found error is occured.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It means 2.jsp is missing from this directory - `/WEB-INF/question-detail/`. Show your Controller code here. You will get multiple options from SO Community.

Comment: 2.jsp it is not jsp page it is the id of question no. 2 and it  is dynamically changed according to question id , here question 2 details is described it may change question to question

Answer (score 0):

I guessed it right. So you would need (AND you are missing, may be) an additional method of this (similar) type. The Id could be of `int`/`long`/`String`(you need to check on this, in the sample/guess below I am using Long):

```
@GetMapping("question-detail/{id}")
public String getQuestionDetail(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("question", someQuestionService.findByQuestionId(Long.valueOf(id)));
    return  "question-detail/"+id;";
}
```

So, the issue is, you getting `not found` (404) because you are missing this end point - `question-detail/{id}` which expects/accepts id as path variable. Not exact match, but you can certainly look at my github repo [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootUserProfile/blob/master/src/main/java/spring/boot/rocks/controllers/AppUserController.java) and [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootUserProfile). You should get idea on what you are missing and doing wrong.

Once you implement above, you also might wanna use `return "redirect:/question-detail/2";` instead of `return "question-detail/"+2;` in your original method's return.

Comment: @RequestMapping(path = "/saveanswer",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String saveAnswer(@Valid @ModelAttribute("answer") AnswerModel answer,BindingResult result,Model model) {
  if(result.hasErrors()) {
   return "question-detail/"+2;
  }else {
   answerDao.saveAnswer(answer);
   return "redirect:/onlinezone.com/question-detail/"+answer.getQuestion_id();
  }
  
 }

Comment: i want to return back when form has some error

Comment: Can you put your project on Github and share the link here?

Comment: https://github.com/krishjava/onlinezone/blob/master/onlinezone/src/main/java/com/onlinezone/front/controller/HomeController.java

Comment: check line no. 190   and post request coming from /question-detail/{id}  id can be dynamic  if it has some error than return to same url

Comment: but when i returning question_detail/2  it is converted into question_detail/2.jsp